# Does chain tension change how hard/easy it is to pedal?

Tags: chain, fixed-gear, tension

I ride a single speed bike and it seems to be tougher than it should be to pedal. It is comparable to one of the higher gears on a multi-speed bike. I'm getting the feeling that my chain may be too tight.

It has a 44:16 gear ratio.

Would a looser chain make it easier to pedal?

Obviously you don't want the chain too loose or you risk having the chain pop off.

Comment: What makes you think that this is not just due to the ratio? While the right tension sure is important, I'm not sure how large of a difference in efficiency you could feel within the range of tensions which properly work at all. Can you compare to another bike with a similar ratio?

Comment: A 44:16 should be pretty normal for most people in a not very hilly area.

Answer (score 10):

If the tension is too high, the drivetrain will bind. If it is too low, the chain will drop (which is dangerous on a fixie, since it can catch and lock up the rear wheel relatively easily).

You basically want the highest tension such that the drivetrain doesn't bind.

See [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/fixed.html#tension) on how to set chain tension properly.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out later today.I'm fairly new to cycling, but i've ended up on Sheldon Brown's site more than once. Is that like the "go-to" site for everything about fixing bikes? It's has really good information the site just seems a little dated.

Comment: Most of the useful information on cycling online is either at sheldonbrown.com or parktool.com.

Comment: The chain could also bind/be loose if it is irregularly worn. Not all the links are going to wear and lengthen in the exact same way.

Comment: @Carel Just to clarify, the bike is new and has been ridden approx. 40 miles. While possible, I don't think it's due to wear.

Comment: RIP Sheldon Brown

Comment: It was 8+ years ago.

Comment: If the chain isn't worn then it could also be a matter of fabrication tolerances and a really too high tension. It happens with new chains. Moving the rear axle forward 1 or 2mm may improve smoothness greatly.

Comment: If its that new, you should be able to take it to the shop you bought it from and get a free adjustment.

Comment: @Batman I made the dumb decision to buy it online so to get it looked at/tuned it will cost me $50. I will probably just take it to the shop anyway.

Comment: @Carel You were right. There was too much tension. I moved the rear axle forward about 1-2mm and now it is noticeably easier.